# accessory button not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code which tries to add a accessory view, but I can't see anything

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }

    //add a button to set to accessory view
    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addsource.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your button programmatically, not in the IB (where you would place it somewhere on the view of cell), so you have to assign a frame position/size as well.

E.g., for just a test try something like this:

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(200, 20, 20, 20);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
cell.accessoryView = button;
```